# How can i get value on click instead of [object MouseEvent] in javaScript

Tags: javascript, servlets

so i have an event Handler on all my buttons. The buttons than call a function that should go to a servlet.

This is the listener on my buttons.

```
    const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("category-button");

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        populateDeleteTable(this.value);
    });
}
```

I gave my function a parameter and when i click on the Button i get an object mouse event.

```
function populateDeleteTable(category) {
```

This is what i get. I painted over the not important parts.

[image]

So basically instead of `[object MouseEvent]` i want the id of the button `einID2`
How do I do that?

EDIT:

Here is the Function. Maybe someone sees the problem.
Current Code

```
const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("category-button");

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) {
buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    populateDeleteTable(event.target.id);
});
}



function populateDeleteTable(category) {

    var servletURL = "../deleteServlet_1"

    console.log(category);

    let xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    
    xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlHttpRequest.readyState === 4 && xmlHttpRequest.status === 200) {

            console.log("test inner")
            console.log(xmlHttpRequest.responseText);

            let itemGetter = JSON.parse(xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
            JSON.stringify(itemGetter);

            var ausgabe = "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Artikel Bezeichnung</th><th>Preis</th><th>Kategorie</th></tr>";

            

            for (var i = 0; i <= itemGetter.length - 1; i++) {


                //servletURL.searchParams.append("lookfor", itemGetter[i].kategorie);
                ausgabe += "<tr><td>";
                ausgabe += itemGetter[i].id;
                ausgabe += "</td><td>";
                ausgabe += itemGetter[i].artikelName;
                ausgabe += "</td><td>";
                ausgabe += itemGetter[i].preis.toFixed(2);
                ausgabe += "</td><td>";
                ausgabe += itemGetter[i].kategorie;
                ausgabe += "</td><td>";
                ausgabe += "<a href= \"deleteServlet_2?id=" + itemGetter[i].id + "\">Delete</a>"

            }
            ausgabe += "</td></tr></table>";
            document.getElementById("listeDeleteB").innerHTML = ausgabe;





        }
    };

    xmlHttpRequest.open("GET", servletURL + "?category=" + encodeURI(category), true);
    xmlHttpRequest.send();
}
```

Comment: event.target.id should return the button id on click

Comment: Or simply `this.id` in the event listener callback

Comment: Both didnt work somehow.

Comment: I edited the post. Is there something is may have overlooked?

Answer (score 1):

Access element you're clicking by `event.target` and then it's *ID* by `event.target.id`
Check out documentation for `event.target`, you can find some more things that'll be useful for you.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    populateDeleteTable(event.target.id);
});
```

Comment: I did copy and paste it. Still does the same. Let me update the code above so you can see.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.